# How to check in node.js if two dates are consecutive?

Tags: node.js, date

I want to check if two given dates are consecutive, like the following:

last_event_dt = 8/1/2013
event_dt = 8/2/2013

Condition would be TRUE

last_event_dt = 8/1/2013
event_dt = 8/3/2013

condition would be FALSE

If found an answer here on stackoverflow for javascript with getDate() but that isn't recognized in node.js

The following code doesn't work:

```
if (event_dt - last_event_dt === 1)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: node.js uses the same v8 engine which runs chrome browser. So if it works on chrome, it will work on node.

Comment: Just remember that if timezone has Daylight savings, you can have days of 23 or 25 hours.
In that case the constant 86400000 should not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date.parse(d2) - Date.parse(d1) === 86400000
```

Comment: Thanks Laurent, it's a nice and simple, elegant solution. Will use this for all kinds of date calculations in the future.

Comment: How would this handle Daylight Saving Time?